# ViewPager goes from first to very last image in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, android-viewpager

I have created an application where I upload images to firebase then retrieve them and display them in a viewpager.
I am able to retrieve all images, but my problem is that when in the viewpager, they go from the first to the very last image very fast (I don't see the other images I only see the first then the last).

I have tried adding a loop that just keeps incrementing a number to kind of delay the application, but it didn't work.
Next I used a handler to as a delayer, but it didn't work.
Here's what my code currently looks like -it's inside a TimerTask class because the viewpager swipes automatically, it's a simple while look

```
    public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
           menuSliderActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int i=0;
                    while(i<sliderImg.size()){
                        while (viewPager.getCurrentItem()==i){
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(i+1);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem()==sliderImg.size()) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }
                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

I have also tried :

```
 public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
           menuSliderActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int i=0;
                    while(i<=sliderImg.size()){
                        if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==i){
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(i+1);
                        } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem()==sliderImg.size()) {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                         }
                        i++;
                    }
                    }
            });  
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? (I am new to android studio and java so I might be using a function -runnable(), run(),...etc) wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one, which uses Thread

***DelayedTask.java***

```java
class DelayedTask extends Thread {
        private Activity activity;
        private int count;
        private int sleepDelay;
        private int totalDelay = 5000;

        public DelayedTask(Activity activity, int count) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.count = count;
            this.sleepDelay = totalDelay / count;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                try {
                    final int j = i;
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(j);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(sleepDelay);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

use this when all images all downloaded

```
DelayedTask delayedTask = new DelayedTask(MainActivity.this, 10 /*no of images*/);
delayedTask.start();
```

Comment: thank you I have tried this code and it works, only I have to swipe through the images myself, they don't just go from one image to another by themselves. help please?

Answer (score 0):

You should use CountDownTimer To Loop your Images in ViewPager. so it will loop slowly as you want.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
```

}.start();

Here is the link

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer